# Различие платных и бесплатных СУБД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Всем добрый вечер. Меня давно интересует такой вопрос. Отличаются ли чем-то платные СУБД (`Oracle`) от бесплатных (`MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `MS SQL Server`, `DB2`)?

Comment: ну и вопрос.. как ты думаешь за что ты платишь?))

Comment: Это я и хочу узнать))

Comment: за поддержку - ты всегда можешь написать/позвонить им и сразу получишь правильный ответ/консультацию

Comment: По типу есть задача, как составить SQL-запрос?)))

Comment: Как один из вариантов - уязвимости(`дыры`) платных СУБД известны на много меньшему числу злоумышленников в довольно большом процентном соотношении.

Comment: А с каких пор MS SQL Server бесплатный?

Comment: Ну, видимо, речь об Express Edition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Суть вопроса лучше всего раскрывается на примере MySQL, поскольку для нее есть два вида лицензий: общедоступная и коммерческая. По сути сам продукт полностью идентичен, но для коммерческой лицензии предполагается ежегодная поддержка. Если сравниваются продукты сами по себе отличные друг от друга Oracle против PostgreSQL, то там может быть плата и за какой-либо особенный функционал продукта.